# MySQL GROUP BY query runs quickly, but not as VIEW

Tags: mysql, view, indexing, group-by, query-optimization

I have a 7 million row InnoDB table in MySQL 5.5. I need to aggregate the table in a view using GROUP BY and SUM. I've researched optimisation tips using EXPLAIN in the MySQL docs, and ensured I have the correct indexes.

The query runs fine as a normal SELECT (1.9s) - But when I turn it into a VIEW, performance is very slow (14s). I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, or if I should be taking a different approach. Any pointers much appreciated.

Here's the table;

```
-- MySQL 5.5.34

CREATE TABLE `reporting_email` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `report_date` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `module_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email_platform` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'UNKNOWN',
  `sends` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `date_idx` (`report_date`),
KEY `grouping_idx` (`report_date`,`country_id`,`email_platform`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ma.reporting_email;
-- 6,868,104 records
```

This query runs quickly;

```
SELECT
  report_date,
  country_id,
  email_platform,
  SUM(sends) AS total_sends
FROM ma.reporting_email
GROUP BY report_date, country_id, email_platform;
-- executes in 1.946 seconds
```

Here's the EXPLAIN - Everything looks okay, I think;

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
1, SIMPLE, reporting_email, index, , grouping_idx, 68, , 6860009,
```

But look what happens when I turn the query into a VIEW;

```
CREATE VIEW ma.reporting_email_vw
AS
SELECT
  report_date,
  country_id,
  email_platform,
  SUM(sends) AS total_sends
FROM ma.reporting_email
GROUP BY report_date, country_id, email_platform;

SELECT * FROM ma.reporting_email_vw;
-- 14.4 seconds to run
```

It now takes 14 seconds to run! Here's the EXPLAIN;

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
1, PRIMARY, <derived2>, ALL, , , , , 19953, 
2, DERIVED, reporting_email, index, , grouping_idx, 68, , 6860009,
```

Comment: Mysql views loses all the indices.

Comment: @ThinkDifferent But jhonan isn't using a view !?!?

Comment: @Strawberry May be I misunderstood the question but he clearly says that normal query takes 1.9s but now when changed to ***VIEW*** it takes 14s

Comment: jhonan's not using a view. They're simply using the same query to create a view.

Comment: They then select everything from that view

Comment: doh - totally missed that

Comment: @ThinkDifferent, no index is needed for `SELECT * FROM ma.reporting_email_vw`.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone! - This was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/05/19/a-workaround-for-the-performance-problems-of-temptable-views/):

> As long as a view avoids aggregation, DISTINCT, GROUP BY, ORDER BY,
>   etc, then it can use the MERGE algorithm. Unfortunately, this means
>   that views of any significant complexity will almost always use the
>   TEMPTABLE algorithm.

What's happening when you perform `SELECT` from the view is the entire result set is copied to a temporary table (you can see this in the `EXPLAIN` result), then your query filter is applied to the results in the temp table and served up.

Since you're not applying any filter to the view (no `WHERE` clause), you may as well just run the original query instead of using the view, to avoid the extra step.

Comment: Thanks @MarcusAdams - So it seems that although the underlying query is using the index for the GROUP BY, the performance hit happens when the results are copied to a temp table in order to supply the view. Makes sense. The end destination for the data is Tableau, so I think I'll run the full SELECT query in Tableau, rather than selecting from the view.

Comment: @jhonan, MySQL still has a lot of optimization work to do regarding views.